# Trying to match more than one class in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

I'm very new to XSLT and trying to format some text for pdf's and I need to match and hide a few elements.

I am currently using:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@outputclass='LC ACaseName']">
```

to match:

```
<p outputclass="LC ACaseName">
```

and it works just fine.

What I now need to do is match 4 or 5 more

> `<p outputclass="<somestring>">`

and apply the same style to them. I could easily just duplicate the above line substituting the different outputclass names each time but this is lazy and I know there must be a correct way of doing this which I should learn.

I hope I have provided enough info here. If I have missed anything please say.

thanks,

Hedley Phillips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple conditions in the predicate:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@outputclass='test' or @outputclass='blah']">
```

Comment: +1 Also a correct answer. Just for brevity, I would use `*[@outputclass[.='test' or .='blah']]`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I especially like the shortened version as some of my conditions are starting to get a little long winded...

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the duplicate...

In XSLT/XPath 1.0:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(
                          '|LC ACaseName|other class|',
                          concat('|',@outputclass,'|')
                       )
                     ]"> 
    <!-- Content Template --> 
<xsl:template>
```

In XSLT/XPath 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@outputclass = ('LC ACaseName','other class')]"> 
    <!-- Content Template --> 
<xsl:template>
```

**Note**: For XSLT/XPath 1.0 solution you need a separator not being part of any item content.